# The Legacy of the Casino Owner - Code

Tags: password, code

So here's my first puzzle for you!

A late casino owner leaves his descendants this letter:

> *Dear my beloved sons Francis and Owen, dear my beloved wife Uma,*
>
> *The **dice** are rolled. You finally made it and as law requires, all of you will get their **split** of the jackpot. The only thing standing in between you and your lawfully acquired wealth is a four-inch wall of ferro-concrete. To open the door to the safe a four digit number is required that you can derive from the below code. Let's see if you are worth your legacy and settle it **once** and for all.*
>
> *Your loving dad/husband Richard*
>
> **3 4 6 A 3 2 5 J 3 1 3 Q 5 K 3 A A 1 2 5 3 6 5 J 2 3 Q 1**

Find the combination!

Hint 1:

> Can you make a sequence of numbers only from it?

Hint 2:

> You can derive all information needed from the letter.

Hint 3:

> No knowledge of specific games is required!

Hint 4:

> Some restructuring is required in the process. (Hint 2 applies for that, too)

Hint 5:

> How many splits are there?

**EDIT:** I updated the description, added a letter to provide better hints to the solution and updated all hints.

Comment: If I solve this, do I also get a cut? I'm not helping a bunch of rich kids get their inheritance for free.

Comment: @IanMacDonald It's role-playing game. Imagine you are one of them, craving for more :P

Comment: Blackjack! I guess the combination is the dealer's hand?

Comment: @Aravind Good idea, but no, no knowledge of specific games is required.

Comment: I assume the pun-intended die is a six-sided die...

Comment: @JoeZ. You are right. But in fact the sides do not matter, the pips do.

Comment: @ProGlockner pips ? Im also thinking blackjack because you chose to use tha a as an a (11) or 1, i dont know much else games where the 1 and a are both an option for the a card.

Comment: @SvenB Yeah pips or whatever these dots on a die are called. Sorry, I'm not native. There is also some card game stuff involved, obviously, but it's largely pretty general, no special card game rules are needed. And as I already stated, the 1 becomes important in the end.

Comment: I presume the sequence of numbers would be either `3 4 6 1 3 2 5 11 3 1 3 12 5 13 3 1 1 1 2 5 3 6 5 11 2 3 12 1` or `3 4 6 14 3 2 5 11 3 1 3 12 5 13 3 14 14 1 2 5 3 6 5 11 2 3 12 1` depending on if Ace is high or low

Comment: @EngineerToast Yeah, looks good. One of them makes up the right format.

Comment: Conjecture. There are an even number of cards (28) so these could be blackjack hands. I don't know of a poker variation that would fit. Does anybody know if this looks like baccarat?

Comment: As I already said, no knowledge of specific games is required to solve this puzzle.

Comment: Noteworthy: The numerals are *only* those that can be found on standard dice.  There are no 7's, 8's, 9's, or 10's.  It's probably safe to assume that there are dice alternating with face cards in some pattern, and they aren't all just cards.  That also resolves the 1 v A issue.  I also found a *really* interesting arrangement that works out really nicely, except it would produce a 6-digit number as a result.

Comment: @Bobson What if I tell you not all numbers matter in the end?

Comment: @ProGlockner - Interesting.  Is `A J Q 3` a step along the way?

Comment: @Bobson No, you don't have to regard isolated fragments of the code. And I was a bit imprecise with my last comment. The numbers that "doesn't matter" matter of course, but not in their numerical value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my second answer, but I must admit that this is, most probably, *not "the canonical answer", but instead is an attempt of the descendants to figure out the right combinations* **=)**

> *The four digit combination is generated by rolling four dice, and those four digits are hidden in the sequence given*, where the sequence is based on the numbers on the cards of a card game (I apologise if I'm using the wrong terms, I'm not native). We can take the sequence of numbers as either `3 4 6 1 3 2 5 11 3 1 3 12 5 13 3 1 1 1 2 5 3 6 5 11 2 3 12 1` or `3 4 6 14 3 2 5 11 3 1 3 12 5 13 3 14 14 1 2 5 3 6 5 11 2 3 12 1` depending on if Ace is high or low (thank you @Engineer Toast). As there are numbers greater than 6 we could apply '*mod 6*' on all numbers. Then, we *brute force the right sequence out!*

Comment: Well, your conclusion in the first part was quite right. :) Though, the way the combination is hidden is different.

Comment: @ProGlockner so every thing exept the way the 4 digit combi is hidden is correct right?

Comment: Yes, and since there's this ambiguity with the ace: its value in this case is 14.

Comment: @ProGlockner i suppose that the alpha-numeric sequence u gave was made by shuffling cards

Comment: If you mean the order of the cards I have to confuse you completely: for some of them it does matter, for the most it doesn't

Comment: @ProGlockner u mean the ones that matter are  the "*1*"s?

Comment: Well, that's something for you to figure out. Maybe you should start by getting the four dice into play.

Comment: @ProGlockner so do u mean that the answer is distributed among the sequence? So the ones that matter are the answer digits (which camoflage pretty well), and the ones that dont are the rest of the sequence charecters, right?

Comment: Nope :P Not his easy

Comment: @ProGlockner but i do deserve an upvote for being this close right? =)

Comment: @ProGlockner also a 5th hint please =)

Comment: I restructured the puzzle description and added a letter... also hints are updated. I hope this improves the process of finding the solution.

Comment: @ProGlockner so the secret behind the restructuring lies in the letters right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much, but I did find an interesting rearrangement of the numbers.  It may be relevant, it may just be coincidence.

> **3** 4 6 A 
>   **3** 2 5 J 
>   **3** 1 3 Q 
>   **5** K 3 A A 1 
>   **2** 5 3 
>   **6** 5 J 2 3 Q 1

All I did was take the first digit (3) as a count, then put the next three characters after it.  Then the next free character became the next count, and so on.  Notice how it works out to *exactly* use up every character, and there's never a card where the count needs to be.  Also noteworthy is that all three `3` columns go Die-Die-Card, and the `6` is an inverse of the pattern from the `5`.

I have no idea whether there's anything to it, though.

Comment: Wow, appreciate the effort you put into this. Seriously good stuff, but just coincidence.

Comment: @ProGlockner - I tried several different ways to split it up, looking for patterns.  Four columns, four rows, on each `1`, on each letter, etc.  This was, by far, the most interesting result, although that doesn't mean that one of the others wasn't the right one.

Comment: Maybe you concentrate on the number four too much.

Comment: @ProGlockner - Hmm.  Good point.  A four digit code could consist of 2 two digit numbers, or a two and two ones.  I'll keep playing with arrangements.

Comment: Take hint 5 into consideration :)

Comment: Also look at Switch's answer. He got the start quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another guess, based on splitting on the `1`'s:

> 3 4 6 A 3 2 5 J 3 1 
>   3 Q 5 K 3 A A 1 
>   2 5 3 6 5 J 2 3 Q 1

This can be rearranged:

> 3 4 6 A 3 
>  2 5 J 3 1 
>  3 Q 5 K 
>  3 A A 1 
>  2 5 3 6 5 
>  J 2 3 Q 1

Both of these arrangements would both produce

> the code 3K5 (or 3135) by taking the center number of each grouping, which is also the number directly above each `1` in the second arrangement.

---

Alternatively, after splitting the lines, convert all letters to numbers as Switch did in his answer (J => 11, Q => 12, K => 13, A => 14)

> 3 4 6 14 3 2 5 11 3 1 
>   3 12 5 13 3 14 14 1 
>   2 5 3 6 5 11 2 3 12 1

Then, split all two-digit numbers into individual digits

> 346143251131 
>  312513314141 
>  253651123121

Note how each line ends on a 1.

An alternative split (going A B C A B C instead of A A A... B B B...) from the original would produce

> 312135312611 
>  445311145522 
>  631123413131

I'm not sure where to go from here, though.  Profit?

Comment: Wow, you come up with ideas I would have never thought of. But as I already said, you really should take a look at Switch's answer. The first step should not be rearranging the sequence but replacing letters with numbers. THEN some restructuring is necessary.

Comment: Some "simple" restructuring I might add...

Comment: @ProGlockner - *Ah!* That's what you meant by looking at his answer.

Comment: @ProGlockner i gues he is right about the spliting. There are 3 splits, one for each of his sons and his wife. The splits were done with 1s in the end cuz 1s are umportant in the end. Right?

Comment: @Switch - That comment just inspired me, but I only get further, not to an answer...

Comment: @ProGlockner - Is this another step in the right direction, or am I going off on a tangent again?

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

> 3135, 5313, or 1353

Here's why:

> Here's the sequence:
>
> 3 4 6 A 3 2 5 J 3 1 3 Q 5 K 3 A A 1 2 5 3 6 5 J 2 3 Q 1
>
> Now lets assume this is cyclical. So the sequence could be written as:
>
> ... *1* 3 4 6 A 3 2 5 J 3 1 3 Q 5 K 3 A A 1 2 5 3 6 5 J 2 3 Q 1 3 4 6 A 3 2 5 J 3...
>
> Notice how it just repeats. Now, let's find the **dice (values rolled from dice to create the combination)** that **split** the **once (ones)**
>
> ... *1* 3 4 6 A **3** 2 5 J 3 *1* 3 Q 5 **K** 3 A A *1* 2 5 3 6 **5** J 2 3 Q *1* 3 4 6 A 3 2 5 J 3...
>
> Now, the K would be 13, and there isn't a 13 on standard casino dice, so it be becomes 1,3
>
> It's possible the code could be any of the three given, depending on how you interpret the cycle. But testing three codes shouldn't be that hard